# How to make "show all" button in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an list with many items. I want to show first 10, and show all after clicking corresponding button. I do it like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/rq8SsE?p=preview
How can I  do the same thing with filter instead of ng-show. In more complicated cases  this method is more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular has a built in limitTo filter. You can apply it to the ng-repeat directive.
http://plnkr.co/edit/aWYzm9?p=preview

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:limitTo

Comment: Fine, but how can I disable filter after click the button?
LimitTo doesn't support Inifinity as argument, only integers

Comment: ng-disable="maxItems==items.length"